# Is there any built in smoke testing tool?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I keep seeing on the CSGO subreddit people who test their smoke throws on what seems a test server where they have unlimited smokes and can activate noclip.

I'd like to try my hand at it, but have no clue how to setup a custom server where I could do such things.

Is there a way to test smokes without setting up a custom server or trying them in matchmaking itself?

Is there some kind of built-in smoke testing tool?

PS: If not, is there some custom servers made for this? What should I look for in the Server browser?

Comment: Server recommendations are off-topic. The rest might be answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are smoke [training maps](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/?id=477197888), open the Workshop and search "smoke training". They are setup in such a way that when you join you have unlimited nades and can see the trajectory.

Alternatively you can run [few commands](http://dathost.net/blog/csgo-practice-config-full-cfg-file-and-list-of-commands-you-might-want/) on a local "Offline with bots" to play around as much as you want.

```
// Server configuration
sv_cheats 1
mp_limitteams 0
mp_autoteambalance 0
mp_freezetime 0
mp_roundtime 60
mp_roundtime_defuse 60
mp_roundtime_hostage 60
mp_maxmoney 99999
mp_startmoney 99999
mp_buytime 9999
mp_buy_anywhere 1
ammo_grenade_limit_total 5
sv_infinite_ammo 1
bot_kick
mp_warmup_end

// Grenade trajectory commands. Note – these don’t work on dedicated servers.
// For dedicated servers, use SourceMod plugin “Nade tails” instead.
sv_grenade_trajectory 1
sv_grenade_trajectory_time 10

// Show bullet impacts
sv_showimpacts 1
sv_showimpacts_time 10

mp_restartgame 1

// Print out so we know the config has been executed.

Say “Practice config enabled”
```

How to install the config on your computer

1. [Download the config file](https://dathost.net/assets/blog/practice.cfg) or create a text-document and paste the config file into it. Name it something along the lines of “practice.cfg”. The .cfg extension is important.
2. Locate your Steam folder and then go to “…\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg”
3. Move the config file into this folder.
4. Start CS:GO and select “Play offline with bots” to start a local server.
5. Open up your console and type “exec practice” (or whatever you named the config file)
6. You’re good to go!

Comment: So not built in, but workshop seems to be picking it up.